# GraphQL Schema: enum or false

Tags: graphql

Is there a way to specify a property whose value is either an `enum` value or a `Boolean`? This did not work:

```
enum PassPermission { request, verify, view, modify }

type Permissions
{
    pass: PassPermission! | Boolean!
}
```

And neither did this:

```
enum PassPermission { request, verify, view, modify }

union PassPermissionOrFalse = PassPermission | Boolean

type Permissions
{
    pass: PassPermissionOrFalse!
}
```

But I want to convey in my schema that the value of `pass` will always be either one of these four string values or `false`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Union Types](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#union-types) to accomplish that. But as it states on the documentation:

> Note that members of a union type need to be concrete object types; you can't create a union type out of interfaces or other unions.

So you cannot use `enum` or scalars like `Boolean` when building a `union` type, but you could do something like:

```
enum permission { request, verify, view, modify }

type PassPermission {
  permissions: permission
}

type PassFalse {
  value: Boolean
}

union Permissions = PassPermission | PassFalse
```

This way the type `Permissions` can have one of 2 types `PassPermission` or `PassFalse`.